# Expected utility

Tags: economics

The figure below describes John's preferences over lotteries for three prizes- $1, $2, and $3, where p1 is the probability of winning $1, and p3 is the probability of winning $3. Assume that John is an expected utility maximizer.

[image]

a) Is John risk averse?

b) Suppose it is additionally known that John prefers a lottery that pays $2 with probability 1/2 and $3 with probability 1/2 to a certain payment of $2.50. Which of the following two lotteries will John prefer? Explain briefly.

• Lottery A: A payment of $2 with probability 1.

• Lottery B: A lottery that pays $2.50 with probability 0.35 and $1 with
probability 0.65.

I can't seem to understand the above question. I first calculated the expected utilities. According to the statement since he prefers the former while he must be risk loving.
However, when I calculate the EU of Lottery A and B, 2 and 1.525, respectively, I don know how to conclude in that case. He is a risk lover but since the expected utility of a lottery is higher than the lottery itself, he shouldn't choose Lottery B. I believe that the right answer is he chooses Lottery A.

Is it correct?

The screenshot of the exercise

[image]

Comment: "Suppose it is additionally known..." This suggests that there may have been some important information stated earlier in the problem. With the limited information we have, this question seems unanswerable. Although as you noted the sure thing has a higher expected value than the risky thing.

Comment: @paw88789 This was the second part of the question. Let me edit the original post.

Comment: Can you just upload the picture of the exercise?

Comment: @callculus42 edited the post.

Comment: @Disintegrators O.K. I must say, that I'm unable to interpret the graph.

Comment: @callculus42 I was thinking of 0.625*3+0.375*1 to find the expected value.

Comment: As  I said, I'm unable to interpret the graph. So I can not relly help

Comment: So if I remember this graph correctly, John is indifferent to a bet with expected payoff 1/2*3+1/2*2=2.5 and a bet with 5/8*3+3/8*1=2.25.